# Unable to Unmount partition in Virtual Box

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox

We have ubuntu 12.04.06 LTS running on a virtual box. We are trying to unmount the partition as it takes a lot of space.

We have extended the new partition in the virtual box from 8GB to 125GB. The new partition does not show on Ubuntu.

We have tried the following commands to unmount

umount /dev/mapper/sqlledger-root and e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/sqlledger-root

It prompts with a message that the device is busy.

we have tried forcefully killing the process :

sudo fuser -km /mnt/share and tried sudo umount /mnt/share

We have allocated 125gb and we are not sure how we can resize the partition of ubuntu in virtual box

Any suggestions would be really helpful

Regards,

Comment: Take a look at [Resizing a Linux Partition (Running in VirtualBox)](http://www.netzgewitter.com/2011/08/resizing-linux-partition/).

Answer (score 1):

Virtual box is creates an environment in which the OS can run INSIDE another partition.  When you install a virtual box drive, it creates a compressed file containing the entire OS that you installed (Ubuntu in this case), as well as some Virtual Box software dependencies to make it all run.  It will not be detected by any partitioning software.

With this in mind, it might be easier to think of the Virtual Box Drive as a large, 125GB application or file, rather than a partition.

If you have allocated too much space to the Virtual Box drive, you have to open the Virtual Box Manager, and delete the entire drive and start over.

Virtual Box Drives only get bigger, not smaller.  All that 125GB of data is being used, mostly by trash data, with only ~8GB or whatever space you have there allocated for Ubuntu.

Think of the trash data as the blank white space on a picture.  It's not empty, it's white (but in this case, many bytes of data).  With that in mind, remember that that file, 125GB will always have that white space, and repartitioning from WITHIN the virtual Ubuntu OS will only create a smaller partition, with junk blank partition space, which will still belong to the 125GB file.

TL;DR

You have to delete the virtual drive altogether, from the Virtual Box Manager, and restart from scratch with a more desirable setup.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. I would re-install the OS in the virtual box and allocate the right amount of space.